# Validate (Possible) File/Directory Path

Tags: validation, file-system, api, vb.net

I am working on a "comprehensive" library for use in my internal applications and I have created a working method (as far as all of my testing has shown thus far) to ensure that a file/directory path is - or, at least, *could* be - legitimate and *should* be accessible to any user of the same application. ***NOTE:*** These are all internal systems not intended for public use or consumption.

I've tried to pull together bits of information/code I've found that address certain aspects of the issue into a "single" method, part of which involves converting an individual user's mapped drives to full UNC paths (`U:\PublicFolder\SomeFile.txt` becomes `\\SERVERNAME\Share\PublicFolder\SomeFile.txt`). On the other hand, if the drive is a local, physical drive on the user's machine, I *don't* want to convert that to UNC (`\\COMPUTERNAME\C$\SomeFolder\SomeFile.txt`), but instead retain the absolute path to the local drive (`C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.txt`) to prevent issues with access privileges. This is what I've come up with, but I'm wondering if this code is a bit too ambitious or overly contrived.

```vb
Public Enum PathType
    File
    Directory
End Enum

Public Shared Function GetRealPath(ByVal file As IO.FileInfo) As String
    Return GetRealPath(file.FullName, PathType.File)
End Function

Public Shared Function GetRealPath(ByVal folder As IO.DirectoryInfo) As String
    Return GetRealPath(folder.FullName, PathType.Directory)
End Function

Public Shared Function GetRealPath(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal pathType As PathType) As String
    Dim FullPath As String = String.Empty

    If filePath Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("No path specified")
    Else
        If filePath.IndexOfAny(IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars) >= 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid")
        Else
            If pathType = PathType.File Then
                Try
                    Dim TempFile As New IO.FileInfo(filePath)

                    If TempFile.Name.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars) >= 0 Then
                        Throw New ArgumentException("The specified file name '" & filePath & "' is invalid")
                    End If

                    TempFile = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw New ArgumentException("The specified file name '" & filePath & "' is invalid", ex)
                End Try
            End If

            ' The path should not contain any invalid characters. Start trying to populate the FullPath variable.
            If IO.Path.IsPathRooted(filePath) Then
                FullPath = filePath
            Else
                Try
                    FullPath = IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePath)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid", ex)
                End Try
            End If

            If Not FullPath.StartsWith("\\") Then
                Dim PathRoot As String = IO.Path.GetPathRoot(FullPath)

                If PathRoot Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(PathRoot) Then
                    FullPath = String.Empty
                    Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid")
                Else
                    If Not IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives.Contains(PathRoot) Then
                        FullPath = String.Empty
                        Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid. Drive '" & PathRoot & "' does not exist.")
                    Else
                        Dim CurrentDrive As New System.IO.DriveInfo(PathRoot)

                        If CurrentDrive.DriveType = DriveType.Network Then
                            Using HKCU As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Network\" & FullPath(0))
                                If Not HKCU Is Nothing Then
                                    FullPath = HKCU.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString() & FullPath.Remove(0, 2).ToString()
                                End If
                            End Using
                        ElseIf Not CurrentDrive.DriveType = DriveType.NoRootDirectory AndAlso Not CurrentDrive.DriveType = DriveType.Unknown Then
                            Dim SubstPath As String = String.Empty

                            If IsSubstPath(FullPath, SubstPath) Then
                                FullPath = SubstPath
                            End If
                        Else
                            FullPath = String.Empty
                            Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid. Drive '" & CurrentDrive.Name & "' does not exist.")
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return FullPath
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function QueryDosDevice(ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpTargetPath As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal ucchMax As Integer) As UInteger
End Function

Private Shared Function IsSubstPath(ByVal pathToTest As String, <Out> ByRef realPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim PathInformation As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder(250)
    Dim DriveLetter As String = Nothing
    Dim WinApiResult As UInteger = 0

    realPath = Nothing

    Try
        ' Get the drive letter of the path
        DriveLetter = IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pathToTest).Replace("\", "")
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        Return False
    End Try

    WinApiResult = QueryDosDevice(DriveLetter, PathInformation, 250)

    If WinApiResult = 0 Then
        ' For debugging
        Dim LastWinError As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

        Return False
    End If

    ' If drive is SUBST'ed, the result will be in the format of "\??\C:\RealPath\".
    If PathInformation.ToString().StartsWith("\??\") Then
        Dim RealRoot As String = PathInformation.ToString().Remove(0, 4)

        RealRoot += If(PathInformation.ToString().EndsWith("\"), "", "\")
        realPath = IO.Path.Combine(RealRoot, pathToTest.Replace(IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pathToTest), ""))

        Return True
    End If

    realPath = pathToTest
    Return False
End Function
```

---

### TESTING DONE

I've run this through a few different tests, although I'm certain I've not been exhaustive in coming up with ways to make it break.  Here are the details I can remember:

**On my computer, drive `S:` is mapped to `\\SERVERNAME\Accounts\`**

I've declared the following variables for use during my testing.

```vb
Dim TestFile As IO.FileInfo
Dim TestFolder As IO.DirectoryInfo
Dim Path As String
```

---

#### INDIVIDUAL TESTS/RESULTS

---

```vb
' Existing Directory
TestFolder = New IO.DirectoryInfo("S:\EXE\0984\")
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath(TestFolder)
```

Correctly returns `\\SERVERNAME\Accounts\EXE\0984\`

---

```vb
' Existing File
TestFile = New IO.FileInfo("S:\EXE\0984\CPI.txt")
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath(TestFile)
```

Correctly returns `\\SERVERNAME\Accounts\EXE\0984\CPI.txt`

---

```vb
' Not actually a file, but it should return the UNC path
TestFile = New IO.FileInfo("S:\EXE\0984")
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath(TestFile)
```

Correctly returns `\\SERVERNAME\Accounts\EXE\0984`

---

```vb
' Directory does not exist, but it should return the absolute path
TestFolder = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\EXE\0984\")
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath(TestFolder)
```

Correctly returns `C:\EXE\0984\`

---

```vb
' Random String
TestFile = New IO.FileInfo("Can I make it break?")
```

Throws an immediate exception before getting to the `GetRealPath()` method due to illegal characters in the path (`?`)

---

```vb
' Random String
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath("Can I make it break?", Common.Utility.PathType.File)
```

Throws exception from inside the `GetRealPath()` method when attempting to convert the `String` value to an `IO.FileInfo` object (*line 29 in the method's code posted above*) due to illegal characters in the path (`?`)

---

```vb
' Random String
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath("Can I make it break?", Common.Utility.PathType.Directory)
```

Throws exception from inside the `GetRealPath()` method when attempting to call `IO.Path.GetFullPath()` on the `String` value (*line 46 in the method's code posted above*) due to illegal characters in the path (`?`)

---

```vb
' Random String
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath("Can I make it break", Common.Utility.PathType.Directory)
' AND
Path = Common.Utility.GetRealPath("Can I make it break", Common.Utility.PathType.File)
```

"Correctly" returns the path to a subfolder of the `Debug` folder of my project:
`D:\Programming\TestApp\bin\Debug\Can I make it break`

I'm not 100% certain that's the behavior I want, but it's *technically* correct, and it makes sense for situations where relative paths can come into play.

---

*Heck, the act of posting these examples has already started answering a few questions in my own head and helped me to think through this a bit better.*

Admittedly, I've thus far been unable to fully test the `SUBST` conditions because I don't have any drives that have been `SUBST`ed and I've been unable thus far to successfully `SUBST` a path that shows up as a valid drive on my Windows 10 machine.

---

### EDIT

I've successfully tested the `SUBST` condition on my local machine (*see how my ignorance and "over-confidence" caused me some grief in [my question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345316/drive-created-by-subst-windows-10-not-reporting-full-path-to-querydosdevice)*). It looks like this is all working correctly, even though, in the end, I may choose to make a few minor modifications, including:

- I may have to add a parameter to define whether or not I want to allow relative paths to be expanded, and/or possibly check for an appropriate character sequence (`./`, `/`, `..`, etc.) at the start of the string before "approving" the return value. Otherwise, pretty much *any* string value passed in could potentially result in a "legitimate" path.
- I've been strongly considering making the "workhorse" overload (`GetRealPath(String, PathType)`) a `Private` method (along with the `PathType` `Enum`) to allow the validation intrinsic to the `IO.FileInfo` and `IO.DirectoryInfo` objects help prevent some of the "unexpected" or "unintended" results from allowing any random `String` input, such as in the last example.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please explain the downvote. If this question is not appropriate for this site in some way, I will gladly delete it. I'm honestly just looking for some insight from those more experienced than myself.

Comment: You tell us  _I have created a working method (as far as all of my testing has shown thus far)_: do you mind sharing these tests with us? Also, since you have a lot of edge cases, it's imperative you document the function to show consumers the specification.

Comment: I'll happily edit in some test/result information as far as I'm able to remember it. I haven't explicitly kept those tests, so I may have to "fudge" (and, of course, obfuscate) a little.

Comment: @dfhwze - Thank you for asking for the examples of testing. I've edited some into the question and, in so doing, I've already found some places where I can do better, as well as "remembered" some issues I had forgotten I wanted to address.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing only on `GetRealPath`

- You can save some level of indentation by returning early. The code would become easier to read.
- The check `If TempFile.Name.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars) >= 0 Then` is superflous because the constructor of `FileInfo` throws an `ArgumentException` if there are any invalid chars in the filename.
- `FileInfo` doesn't hold unmanaged ressources hence you don't need to set it to `Nothing`.
- It is always better to catch specific exceptions.
- Throwing an Exception inside a `If` block makes the `Else` redundant.
- Checking if a string `Is Nothing OrElse IsNullOrEmpty` can be replaced by just the call to `IsNullOrEmpty`.
- You don't need to set `FullPath = String.Empty` if at the next line of code you are throwing an exception.
- Althought VB.NET is case insensitiv you should name your variables using `camelCase` casing.

Summing up the mentioned changes (except for the specific exception part) will look like so

```
Public Shared Function GetRealPath(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal pathType As PathType) As String
    Dim fullPath As String = String.Empty

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("No path specified")
    End If
    If filePath.IndexOfAny(IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars) >= 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid")
    End If

    If pathType = PathType.File Then
        Try
            Dim tempFile As New IO.FileInfo(filePath)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ArgumentException("The specified file name '" & filePath & "' is invalid", ex)
        End Try
    End If

    ' The path should not contain any invalid characters. Start trying to populate the FullPath variable.
    If IO.Path.IsPathRooted(filePath) Then
        fullPath = filePath
    Else
        Try
            fullPath = IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePath)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid", ex)
        End Try
    End If

    If fullPath.StartsWith("\\") Then
        Return fullPath
    End If

    Dim pathRoot As String = IO.Path.GetPathRoot(fullPath)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathRoot) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid")
    End If

    If Not IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives.Contains(pathRoot) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid. Drive '" & pathRoot & "' does not exist.")
    End If

    Dim currentDrive As New System.IO.DriveInfo(pathRoot)

    If currentDrive.DriveType = DriveType.Network Then
        Using HKCU As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Network\" & fullPath(0))
            If Not HKCU Is Nothing Then
                fullPath = HKCU.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString() & fullPath.Remove(0, 2).ToString()
            End If
        End Using
    ElseIf Not currentDrive.DriveType = DriveType.NoRootDirectory AndAlso Not currentDrive.DriveType = DriveType.Unknown Then
        Dim SubstPath As String = String.Empty

        If IsSubstPath(fullPath, SubstPath) Then
            fullPath = SubstPath
        End If
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("The specified path '" & filePath & "' is invalid. Drive '" & currentDrive.Name & "' does not exist.")
    End If

    Return fullPath
End Function
```